# How to add parentheses to math operations in django template?

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

I have a math operation that requires parentheses in Django's template. However, if I put them, I am getting the error in the attachment. When I remove them the program is running but the results are not correct.
Below is my code in the template:

```
{% if salaireImposable < 150000 %}
   <td> {{ salaireImposable|multiply:0.00|floatformat:0 }} </td>
{% elif  salaireImposable >= 150000 and salaireImposable <= 500000 %}
   <td> {{ 150000|add:"-0"|multiply:0.00|add:salaireImposable|add:"-150000"|multiply:0.05|floatformat }}</td>
{% elif salaireImposable >= 500000 and salaireImposable <= 1000000 %}
   <td>{{ 500000|add:"-150000"|multiply:0.05|add:salaireImposable|add:"-500000"|multiply:0.1|floatformat }}</td>
{% elif salaireImposable >= 1000000 and salaireImposable <= 1500000 %}
    <td>{{ 500000|add:"-150000"|multiply:0.05|add:(1000000|add:"-500000")|multiply:0.1|add:(salaireImposable|add:"-1000000")|multiply:0.15|floatformat}}</td>
{% elif salaireImposable >= 1500000 and salaireImposable <= 2500000 %}
   <td>{{500000|add:"-150000"|multiply:0.05|add:1000000|add:"-500000"|multiply:0.1|add:1500000|add:"-1000000"|multiply:0.15|add:salaireImposable|add:"-1500000"|multiply:0.2|floatformat:0 }}</td>
{% elif salaireImposable >= 2500000 and salaireImposable <= 3500000 %}
   <td> {{500000|add:"-150000"|multiply:0.05|add:1000000|add:"-500000"|multiply:0.1|add:1500000|add:"-1000000"|multiply:0.15|add:2500000|add:"-1500000"|multiply:0.2|add:salaireImposable|add:"-2500000"|multiply:0.25|floatformat:0 }}</td>
{% else %}
<td>{{ 500000|add:"-150000"|multiply:0.05|add:1000000|add:"-500000"|multiply:0.1|add:1500000|add:"-1000000"|multiply:0.15|add:2500000|add:"-1500000"|multiply:0.2|add:3500000|add:"-2500000"|multiply:0.25|add:salaireImposable|add:"-3500000"|multiply:0.30|floatformat:0 }}
</td>
{% endif %}
```

Here is the way I did it in a view and the result are ok:

```
if float(salaireBrut) < 150000:
      salaireImposable = float(salaireBrut)*0.00
elif 150000 <= float(salaireBrut) <= 500000:
      salaireImposable=(150000-0)*0.00+(float(salaireBrut)-150000)*0.05
elif 500000 <= float(salaireBrut) <= 1000000:
      salaireImposable = (500000-150000)*0.05+(float(salaireBrut)-500000)*0.1
elif 1000000 <= float(salaireBrut) <=1500000:
      salaireImposable = (500000-150000)*0.05+(1000000-500000)*0.1+(float(salaireBrut)-1000000)*0.15
elif 1500000 <=float(salaireBrut)<= 2500000:
      salaireImposable = (500000-150000)*0.05+(1000000-500000)*0.1+(1500000-1000000)*0.15+\
                               (float(salaireBrut)-1500000)*0.2
elif 2500000 <= float(salaireBrut) <= 3500000:
      salaireImposable = (500000-150000)*0.05+(1000000-500000)*0.1+(1500000-1000000)*0.15+\
                               (2500000-1500000)*0.2+(float(salaireBrut)-2500000)*0.25
else:
      salaireImposable =(500000-150000)*0.05+(1000000-500000)*0.1+(1500000-1000000)*0.15+(2500000-1500000)*0.2+(3500000-2500000)*0.25+(float(salaireBrut)-3500000)*0.3
```

[image]

I would like to know how can I make parentheses like this: `{{(500000|add:"-150000")|multiply:0.05|add:(salaireImposable|add:"-500000")|multiply:0.1}}`so that, resutls will be correct.

Please assist me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by calculating the same in its models instead of in its view or template and the results are perfect

Here are my solutions:

```
def get_SalaireImposable(self):
    salaireImposable= Decimal(float(self.salaire_de_base + (self.mutuelle_de_sante*(Decimal(0.1))) + self.caisse_de_retraite + self.prime_d_anciennete + self.prime_de_logement + \
           self.heures_supplementaires + self.autre_prime)*12*0.7)
    return salaireImposable

def get_IRPP(self):

    if self.get_SalaireImposable()<150000:
        total_irpp=float(self.get_SalaireImposable())*0.00
        return total_irpp
    elif 150000 <= float(self.get_SalaireImposable()) <= 500000:
        total_irpp = float((150000-0)*0.00+(float(self.get_SalaireImposable())-150000)*0.05)
        return total_irpp
    elif 500000 <= float(self.get_SalaireImposable()) <= 1000000:
        total_irpp=float((500000-150000)*0.05+(float(self.get_SalaireImposable())-500000)*0.1)
        return total_irpp
    elif 1000000 <= float(self.get_SalaireImposable()) <= 1500000:
        total_irpp=float((500000-150000)*0.05+(1000000-500000)*0.1+(float(self.get_SalaireImposable())-1000000)*0.15)
        return total_irpp
    elif 1500000 <= float(self.get_SalaireImposable()) <= 2500000:
        total_irpp=float((500000-150000)*0.05+(1000000-500000)*0.1+(1500000-1000000)*0.15+\
                               (float(self.get_SalaireImposable())-1500000)*0.2)
        return total_irpp
    elif 2500000 <= float(self.get_SalaireImposable()) <= 3500000:
        total_irpp=float((500000-150000)*0.05+(1000000-500000)*0.1+(1500000-1000000)*0.15+\
                               (2500000-1500000)*0.2+(float(self.get_SalaireImposable())-2500000)*0.25)
        return total_irpp
    else:
        total_irpp=float((500000-150000)*0.05+(1000000-500000)*0.1+(1500000-1000000)*0.15+(2500000-1500000)*0.2+\
                              (3500000-2500000)*0.25+(float(self.get_SalaireImposable())-3500000)*0.3)
        return total_irpp
```

Comment: This isn't the answer to your initial question